# how to write unit for subscribe callback - Jasmine / Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit test of a class now I want to assign mock value to "**tableTrans**" but I am not able to mock this part **.subscribe(data =>**

Need help?

```
 ngOnInit() { 
    this.subscription.add(combineLatest([$stats, this.init()]).subscribe(data => {
      // 1. assign data
      this.tableTrans = this.translation.team.burnupAnalysis.table;
      const tableTitle = this.translation.titles.export.bunUpAnalysisTableTitle;
          
    }));
  }
```

I tried to mock it but did not work

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BurnupDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const spy = spyOn(component.subscription, 'add').and.callFake((data) => {
      return ''
  })
```

Comment: Hi, might you add how `$stats` and `this.init()` and `this.translation` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out that I had to fill mock data for **this.init()** and **this.translation** in my store's initial state.